# Trying to . convert a value to a name during output

Tags: postgresql, switch-statement, case, return-value

the values returned in column `a.user_id` are id numbers. I would like to return them as a name or initials e.g. 1 = Chris O or C.ONeill

I have tried CASE function but did not know where to put it

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  sb.start_time::date AS shift_date,
  i.title AS industry,
  wl.name AS venue_name,
  w.first_name,
  w.last_name,
  MIN(cs.start_time::date) AS first_completed_shift,
  i.title AS industry,
  w.interviewed_on AS induction_date,
  d.issue_date AS edbs_issue_date,
  d.created_at AS date_dbs_added,
  a.user_id    --IS IT POSSIBLE TO GET THESE AS VALUES,e.g. a.user_id '1' = 'Chris O or C.ONeill' USING USER NAMES INSTEAD OF USER ID?
FROM shift_bookings sb
JOIN jobs j ON sb.job_id = j.id
JOIN listings l ON j.listing_id = l.id
JOIN work_locations wl ON l.venue_id = wl.id
JOIN workers w ON sb.worker_id = w.id
JOIN completed_shifts cs ON w.id = cs.worker_id
JOIN documents d ON w.id = d.documentable_id
JOIN audits a ON d.id = a.auditable_id
JOIN industries i ON j.industry_id = i.id
 WHERE sb.shift_id IN (253106)
 AND d.document_type_id = 33
 AND a.auditable_type = 'Document'
 GROUP BY
  sb.start_time::date,
  wl.name,
  w.first_name,
  w.last_name,
  i.title,
  w.interviewed_on,
  d.issue_date,
  d.created_at,
  a.user_id
```

a.user_id output will be something else I can set

Comment: Join the table that holds the users and output the name.

Comment: The table just holds ID numbers